# Галерея изображений на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо сделать галерею изображений на сайте, такую, чтобы картинки разного размера, размещались в 5 колонок, но без row(?), то есть, чтобы нижняя картинка прилипала к верхней.

Пытался найти информацию в интернете, но не знаю как правильно составить запрос, по моим запросам показывает только как сделать галереи, в которых нужно листать картинки...

Пытался сделать display: grid;, но получается вот это:
[image]

А вот как мне нужно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вбейте в поиск masonry css grid

Answer (score 1):

**index.html**

```html
<!-- Блок, со списком изображений -->
<div class="content">
    <img src="image_1.webp" class="content__image">
    <img src="image_2.webp" class="content__image">
    <img src="image_3.webp" class="content__image">
    <!-- ...и так далее -->
</div>
```

**style.css**

```css
.content {
    line-height: 0; /* Убираем высоту строки у всех изображений */
    column-count: 5; /* Устанавливаем кол-во колонок */
    column-gap: 0; /* Убираем отступы между колонками */
}

.content__image {
    width: 100%; /* Изображение на всю ширину колонки */
    height: auto; /* Высота изображения определяется автоматически */
}
```

Постоянно когда задам вопрос, сразу сам нахожу ответ...

Comment: В данном виде не совсем понятно как именно ваш ответ решает задачу, отредактируйте ответ так, чтобы он содержал конкретное решение вместе с его объяснением.